# ng-click function not working like I expect (or at all)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call function with argument taken from input using ng-click

html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name">
<button ng-click="$scope.myFunction(name)">  CLICK  </button>
```

js:

```
myApp.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
$scope.myFunction = function (name) {
    console.log("Name: " + name);
}
}]);
```

There are no errors, but when I press button, nothing happen.

Comment: Have you declared your app and controller in the html? Also you dont need to pass name, you access it in the model with $scope.name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your ng click is wrong

```
<button ng-click="myFunction(name)">  CLICK  </button>
```

Comment: It would work just as well using $scope.myFunction, would it not?

Comment: This is correct answer. Of course there is no `$scope.$scope.myFunction` declared in controller, that's why it doesn't work in OP's code.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

$scope is not required when referencing a variable or function in a controller.
You should write it as Teliren suggested:

```
<button ng-click="myFunction(name)">  CLICK  </button>
```

I would also suggest that you read about 'controllerAs' declaration: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController (introduced in version 1.2) which makes your view more readable.